Installation issues on windows 10
While trying to install Ubuntu with BalenaEtcher I get a error(0,h.request Metadata)is not a funtion. I currently have windows.

You've provided few specifics for us to help with, you've not told us what Ubuntu product & release of that product you downloaded; if it was correct architecture for your device, what validation you made to ensure it was correct, after writing to media if you validated that write etc... Did you follow official documentation for your unstated Ubuntu product etc.

This question is similar to: How do I install Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Etcher questions might be more productively directed to Etcher support. The Ubuntu .iso was merely one possible payload.

This question is similar to: What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: Error: (0 , h.requestMetadata) is not a function. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Since you are on Windows, Try Rufus instead.
Go to https://rufus.ie/en/ to download.
